# Peewee Python - only receive the ID after query the Database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, peewee

so i am trying to use peewee to handle all my db-stuff.

```
from peewee import * 
from datetime import datetime

db = MySQLDatabase('peeweetest', user='peeweetest', password='peeweetest', host='127.0.0.1')
db.connect()

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(null=False)
    creationTime = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    password = CharField(max_length=100)

    def store(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.save()

u = User.get(User.id == 2)
print(u)
```

My problem is in the last 2 rows. I am trying to get the User with the ID 2 in the database (the user exists!) but when i print out the result, the user-variable does not contain the user-object, it only contains the ID 2.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because that's [how `peewee.Model` defines the `__str__` method](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py#L6208), quite simply. This is probably documented FWIW.

IOW: you have your model instance, it's just that it only prints it's id. And you could have found out by yourself inspecting your variable in the debugger or Python shell.